# How to open youtube video on UIButton action in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want open youtube video on UIButton action and after finishing youtube video. The control come to application by clicking DONE button, How we can achieve this?

Comment: This is NOT a 'I can haz teh codez?' site, please do some more research.

Answer (score 0):

1: **Create a UIWebView with frame**

2: **Add it as a SuView**

3: **loadRequest using URL**

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com]]];
```